# Pass back selected item from picker to view model instead of entire object using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, events, mvvm

So i have the following picker with a list of strings as item source. Everything works fine except i don't like how i have to pass back the entire object to the view model. What i am trying to do is only pass back the selected item to viewmodel.

XAML:

```
<Picker x:Name="EventTypePicker" ItemsSource="{Binding EventTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding EventType}">
    <Picker.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="SelectedIndexChanged">
            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EventTypePickerSelectionChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Reference EventTypePicker}"/>
                </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
    </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>
```

ViewModel:

```
//obj is the picker object. Would prefer for this just to be the selected item
private void OnEventTypeChange(object obj) {
    var picker = ((Xamarin.Forms.Picker) obj).SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Essentially what i would like to accomplish is something like following:

```
CommandParameter="{Reference EventTypePicker.SelectedItem}"
```

Instead of:

```
CommandParameter="{Reference EventTypePicker}"
```

Comment: @Andrew Derp way overthinking this. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already binding the SelectedItem to a property called EventType on your view model. You should be able to just use that property.

In the XAML, you can drop the CommandParameter:

```
<Picker x:Name="EventTypePicker" ItemsSource="{Binding EventTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding EventType}">
    <Picker.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="SelectedIndexChanged">
            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EventTypePickerSelectionChangeCommand}" />
        </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
    </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>
```

And then in the view model, check your EventType property:

```
private void OnEventTypeChange() {
    var selectedItem = EventType;
}
```